# Clarification regarding SQL syntax case sensitivity

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have seen some articles about case sensitivity where keywords were concerned, but I am a bit confused about something, and not wanting to necro-post I decided to post this here.

I am using SQL Server Management Studio and I am seeing SQL code like this:

```
SELECT * from custTable as A
INNER JOIN custTable as a
ON A.custID = a.custID
```

And then I also see SQL code like this

```
SELECT A.CustID FROM custTable A 
INNER JOIN
(SELECT a.CustID FROM custTable a
    JOIN
    (SELECT A.CustID FROM custTable A
        JOIN 
        (SELECT CustID FROM custTable
        WHERE  [CustID] = 1
        GROUP BY [CustID] ) ap ON A.CustID = ap.CustID  
        GROUP BY A.[CustID] ) m ON A.CustID = m.CustID ) AP ON ap.CustID = A.CustID
```

Apparently, the SQL code is considered case sensitive with regards to aliases. But, have seen the similar code as above written something like this:

```
SELECT A.CustID FROM custtable A 
INNER JOIN
(SELECT a.CustID FROM CustTable a
    JOIN
    (SELECT A.CustID FROM CUSTTABLE A
        JOIN 
        (SELECT CustID FROM Custtable
        WHERE  [CustID] = 1
        GROUP BY [CustID] ) ap ON A.CustID = ap.CustID  
        GROUP BY A.[CustID] ) m ON A.CustID = m.CustID ) AP ON ap.CustID = A.CustID
```

Apparently, the SQL code is considered case INsensitive with regards to table names.

Is this because table names are basically string constants and aliases are like local variables?

Answer (score 2):

In general, SQL Server is not case sensitive with respect to keywords, aliases, or table names.

In your examples, the aliases for "a" and "A" are equivalent.  However, they are in different scopes.  Notice that the `on` clauses always have different aliases "ap" and "A", "A" and "m", and so on.

You can *make* your SQL Server instance case sensitive if you want (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx)).  According to the documentation, SQL Server reserves both the upper and lower case versions of reserved words.  I don't know if mixed case reserved words are also reserved.

Comment: `SELECT cAsE wHeN 1 = 1 THEN 'one' ELSE 'zero' eND` >> 'one' So yes it reserves mixed case too.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski . . . The question is not whether it recognized mixed case.  The question is whether a variable called [fROM] and [From] would be different, in a case-sensitive collation.  My understanding of the documentation is that [FROM] and [from] would be the same in that case.

Comment: From that link: `The collation of an identifier depends on the level at which it is defined. Identifiers of instance-level objects, such as logins and database names, are assigned the default collation of the instance. Identifiers of objects in a database, such as tables, views, and column names, are assigned the default collation of the database. For example, two tables with names that differ only in case can be created in a database that has case-sensitive collation, but cannot be created in a database that has case-insensitive collation.`